# Different result on desktop and iPhone

Tags: html, css

I have this two snapshot: http://snag.gy/uq7on.jpg (desktop) and http://snag.gy/8rg6n.jpg (iPhone 5). I don't know what to do to have the same structure on both, as you can see the paragraph "En ovra afrontamos ..." goes down..

Here is the site: http://www.ovra.es

This is the code of the paragraph:

```
p {
  line-height: 21px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: normal;
  padding-right: 45px;
}
```

Comment: you can use media query to make your site the same structure on both
http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are many answers to your question. Here's mine:

Add the following CSS for the `.der` element:

```
body main section.razones .der {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Then remove the `margin-left` property from the `.izq` and add it to the `.bocadillo` and the `ul`:

```
body main section.razones .izq {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
body main section.razones .izq .bocadillo, body main section.razones .izq ul {
    margin-right: 40px;
}
```